# Camera Video streaming control (CaptureElement) not available for Winui3 c#

Tags: camera, winui-3

I am using WinUi3 for streaming Camera video but this following stream control not available in WinUI3 :

**CaptureElement** not working

please help Which control i should use for camera /video streaming ?

[image: img]

Comment: Which version of WinUI 3 are you using? WinUI 3 is still very much in development and,  in our experience, still full of bugs. E.g. drag and drop is still partially broken and we get tons of weird exceptions in the debug console from the winTR core.

Comment: Please read [this](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4710#issuecomment-897866747)

Comment: Thanks for response .Using c# ,desktop app ,framework .net6 ,vs 2022.

this code is working but capturing image only ,but I need to show camera streaming on the Form (winui form ) .

 var captureUI = new WinUIExtensions.CameraCaptureUI(this);
    var file = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    if (file != null)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage()
        {
            UriSource = new System.Uri(file.Path),
        };
        this.image.Source = bitmapImage;
    }

Comment: No that's not what I asked, the specific version of WinUI 3 matters. The rest is not important. As winui 3 is still in development, they're constantly releasing updates. (Microsoft saying winui 3 is "production ready" is just marketing talking. By far not everything is finished,  and there are a lot of bugs in released features)

Comment: Ok thanks.

Not facing any bug , just looking for right control for camera streaming .

Comment: Then, for the moment, you should try implementing it with ``DirectShow``. You can find some sample code in the link provided by @JHBonarius.

Answer (score 1):

CaptureElement not yet supported on WinUI3, however workaround does exists.
The simplest alternative is: Capture the media frames, and render them on Image Element to make a preview.

```
<!--CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreview" Width="640" Height="480" /-->
<Image x:Name="imagePreview" Stretch="Fill" Width="640" Height="480" />
```

Test sample located at: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4710#issuecomment-1296906888